# MySQL Select rows with same FK but different values in other row

Tags: mysql

I am going back through and auditing some database entries and need a query to find the rows I need to work on.

I have tried a few subqueries but I could not get near what I'm looking for.

An example table would be:

```
code_id     id     exchange
1           23     5
2           23     5
3           24     5
4           24     7
5           25     5
6           26     5
```

Where all I want to extract is rows 3 and 4.  I need to know where the id column is the same but exchange is different.

I think if I get this, I'll be able to build the other 2 tables into the query.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM my_table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT exchange) > 1
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/029e9/1/0).

Comment: I got an error about the NATURAL keyword but it still worked lol.. but that was what I needed will mark as accpeted in 5 minutes when it lets me! Thank you so much!